# JavaScript title switching issues

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
    function twofomr() {
      onclick = document.getElementById('dibba_lo').style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementById('reg_dibba').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('dibbaT2').innerHTML = "Be a part of NoobSnoop";
    }

    function onefomr() {
      onclick = document.getElementById('reg_dibba').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('dibba_lo').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('dibbaT1').innerHTML = "Quick get in !";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div id="icon">
        <a id="icon" type="image" imgsrc="Save.BMP" "></a></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav ">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link active " aria-current="page " href="# ">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="# ">Features</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="textb1 " class="textb1 ">
            <H2 class="dibbaT " id="dibbaT1 ""></H2>
      </div>
      <div id="reg_dibba" ,class='b_dibba'>
        <form action="" class="dibba" ,id="regform" ,method="post">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">What's your name? </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="What do they call you?" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">What's your email? </label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="What do they call you?" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Set your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="piss" id="piss" class="form-control" placeholder="Set a password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Confirm your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="piss2" id="piss2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div id="cnfrmpass">`</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" ,name="sbt" , class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Submit </button>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button onclick="onefomr()" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Login </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="textb2" class="textb2">
        <H2 class="dibbaT" id="dibbaT2"></H2>
      </div>
      <div id="dibba_lo" class="m_dibba" style="display: none;">
        <form action="" class="dibba_lo" ,id="formlogin" ,method="post">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">What's your email? </label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="What your email address?" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Set your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="piss_m" id="piss" class="form-control" placeholder="Set a password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" ,name="btnlog" , class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Take me In </button>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button onclick="twofomr()" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Register </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I wrote this piece of code, it is supposed to change the login and register form with changing headings. It shows both headings at once in the wrong place. Can someone point me to what is going wrong? Any help is appreciated in advance.

I have tried creating two separate DIV tags but that didn't work, I gave an inline script but that broke the code. I have given each heading it's own heading, now it is changing positions.

Comment: You never call onefomr() nor twofomr()

Comment: <button onclick="onefomr()" is that not all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed your code.
Don't use comma `,` to separate element attributes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div id="icon">
        <a id="icon" type="image" imgsrc="Save.BMP"></a></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="# ">Features</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="textb1" class="textb1">
            <H2 class="dibbaT" id="dibbaT1"></H2>
      </div>
      <div id="reg_dibba" class="b_dibba">
        <form action="" class="dibba" id="regform" method="post">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">What's your name? </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="What do they call you?" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">What's your email? </label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="What do they call you?" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Set your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="piss" id="piss" class="form-control" placeholder="Set a password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Confirm your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="piss2" id="piss2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div id="cnfrmpass"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" name="sbt" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Submit </button>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button onclick="onefomr()" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Login </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="textb2" class="textb2">
        <H2 class="dibbaT" id="dibbaT2"></H2>
      </div>
      <div id="dibba_lo" class="m_dibba" style="display: none;">
        <form action="" class="dibba_lo" id="formlogin" method="post">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">What's your email? </label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="What your email address?" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Set your password</label>
            <input type="password" name="piss_m" id="piss" class="form-control" placeholder="Set a password" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="submit" name="btnlog" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Take me In </button>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <button onclick="twofomr()" class="btn btn-primary mb-3"> Register </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
    function twofomr() {
      var regButton = document.getElementById('dibba_lo').style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementById('reg_dibba').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('dibbaT2').innerHTML = "Be a part of NoobSnoop";
    }

    function onefomr() {
      var loginButton = document.getElementById('reg_dibba').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('dibba_lo').style.display = '';
      document.getElementById('dibbaT1').innerHTML = "Quick get in !";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```